# REST API authentication tokens with grails

Tags: rest, grails, token, restful-authentication

what is the best way to apply token authentication for grails rest api?

I found the following plugin

http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest

but the plugin has a problem when a request comes from other domains

Comment: can you provide more details? what you mean by "it has a problem"? did you configure CORS?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov pleas edited question, I have tried adding CORS plugin but the problem still

Comment: I used spring security core plugin with my custom configuration